# Would like to auto-mount two FAT flash drives with the same names

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I would like to auto-mount a flash drive I have called "flash". Infact I have 2 drives with the same name. Both FAT.

I would like ideally which ever one is connected when the system boots to be mounted. Is this possible? Or does auto mount work on an identifier beyond the name?

Comment: Have you considered renaming the FAT partition on one of the drives? it can be done easily using gparted

Comment: So renaming the fat partitions the same thing?

Comment: The drive name comes from the partition name by changing the partition name on one of the drives you would bypass your issue

Comment: The label ('flash' in your case) shouldn't affect the auto-mounting. Ubuntu will mount the drives in separate locations and use these locations to identify them. I labeled a USB Drive and a SD Card with the same names and connected them both at the same time. One is mounted at `/dev/sdb` and the other is at `/dev/sdc`. These are the identifiers that will be used by the operating system rather than the label.

Comment: +1 @Merri - If you plug both flash drives in, Ubuntu will create two folders in `/mnt` on which the devices will be mounted: one called "flash" and the other named "flash_".

Comment: @searchfgold6789 not in `/mnt` but in `/media`... smells like a server guy here :P

Comment: By "which ever is connected", do you mean to mount only one of the two (if both are connected)?

Comment: You don't say which Ubuntu version or GUI?

Comment: If it is Unity, then gvfs mounts the flash disk.  If it is not unity, then udev handles it. I've not tried it, but turning off gvfs automount and adding 'disk-by-id' to /fstab might work, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/mounting-usb-disks-automatically-how-it-works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit your `/etc/fstab` and add the following line to do this easily. But you may understand the risks of doing so.

```
LABEL=flash /media/where_will_be_mounted vfat defaults 0 0
```

Ok, lets boil down each option:

- `LABEL=flash`: tells the system to mount any driver with the **label** flash
- `/media/where_will_be_mounted`: Self-explanatory, you should already have the path created before mounting.
- `vfat`: you said the filesystem will be FAT **always**, if it's not FAT it will fail.
- `defaults`: This set up the driver with the default mount options for the filesystem, equivalent to `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async`. The important part here is the `auto`, that tells the system to mount automatically the filesystem when `mount -a` is issued, like it does at boot.
- `0`: They are dump and fscheck options, you most likely won't want this.

Comment: just a quick question, will vfat work for fat32?

Comment: Any FAT partition is mounted using `vfat` so, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is simple - rename one of them.

Remember that the UUID is very specific to that particular flash drive, so once you make that change in your system it will only work with that exact drive.

If it fails then you would need to go through this whole process again.

It makes a lot more sense for them to have separate names.  Software will have a simple time addressing them without any funny business.

If it needs to go to another computer with that name, then simply eject the other one and then rename it back so the other system will recognize it.

And your primary system will always recognize the drive by name, whether natively or if you use pmount.

I would never alter my system internally just to support a fragile piece like a flash drive.

If you do it this way it will work even on a copy (or a restoration from a backup).

The only reason I can imagine for the UUID method is if you are in a highly secure environment where every flash drive is catalogued.

It just makes sense to build your processes to be fault-tolerant.

Answer (score -1):

Connect both drives, open a terminal (maximize it) and run

```
sudo blkid -olist
```

Take note of the UUID of your flash drives. Now write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

first_uuid=<first-drive-uuid>
second_uuid=<second-drive-uuid>

udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$first_uuid
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$second_uuid
```

(Substitute `<first-drive-uuid>` and `<second-drive-uuid>` with the UUID's of the drives.)

Make the script executable, and add it to **Startup Applications** or to some initialization script.

Answer (score -1):

Create two directories `flash1` `flash2` wherever you want to mount the drive (e.g. ~/flash1)

Perform the following steps for each drive

1. Insert flash drive and determine the device name (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`)
2. run the command `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`
3. Write down or copy the UUID somewhere.
4. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
5. add the line: `UUID=<uuidfordevice> ~/flash1 vfat defaults 0  0`

And Repeat with the other drive.

You might be able to just use one mount directory (flash) if you only ever have one in at a time, but I would have separate directories for each drive.